# umbraco debugging not working properly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, umbraco

i create a usercontrol(webapp1.ascx) and link it with umbraco.also i copy the dll and paste it in the umbraco bin folder.my problem is that breakpoint is not catching.i tried 'attach to process' and done it properly.can any one tell me a solution?

please go throug  [this url](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/debugging) .I followed the same method,bt didnt work

cheers

Comment: did you copy all your project dlls and ascx control? The dlls and controls in umbraco must be same as your project

Comment: yeah...everythng s ok except this break point issue

Comment: how you setup the umbraco website. Is it in wwroot ie as localhost?

Comment: yes...put my folder in wwwroot

Comment: so are you browsing like http://localhost??

Comment: which process you are attaching?

Comment: can you please check the option **show all processes** while attaching. and check whether it contains more than one w3wp process

Comment: no...there is only 1 w3wp process...

Comment: we can only attach a process in administrator mode r8?

Comment: usually we done it as an Admin user.. but dont know whether its a must. Are you using a VPC with ms server 2003 os

Comment: @ranjenanil let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1142/discussion-between-mahesh-and-ranjenanil)

Comment: error message(the breakpoint will not currently hit.no symbols have been loaded for this document.... )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug your user control in another context - be it Umbraco or anything else- you also need to provide the user control's .pdb file. Else your breakpoints won't work.

Comment: i didnt get please go throug this url http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/debugging .I followed the same method,bt didnt work

Comment: where would you put the pdb file in the umbraco directory? in the bin with the dll?

Comment: Where should I put this pdb file? and in the video I think that he is debugging his own solution and not the umbraco website